# How to align the elements inside tuples that are inside a list?

Tags: python

so let's say i have a list which contains various tuples e.g :

```
PPL = [("Amy",2393,93489348,84389),
       ("Blaise",4937439,954975,4387494),
       ("Mint",843984,94374,9584)]
```

What i want to do is sort the numbers which are in the same position as the others and then order them to largest to smallest like :

```
for the numbers in 2nd row : (4937439,843984,2393)
"    "    "     in 3rd row : (93489348,954975,94374)
```

and all on...
How may i do this with a code? >.< ( in python )

Comment: Could you describe the exact expected output as a python object ? Your question is not clear at all. Do you expect this  `PPL = [("Amy",4937439,93489348,4387494),
       ("Blaise",843984,954975,84389),
       ("Mint",2393,94374,9584)]` ? Or just `[(4937439,843984,2393),(93489348,954975,94374),(4387494,84389,9584)]` ? Or `[("Amy",4937439,843984,2393),("Blaise", 93489348,954975,94374),("Mint",4387494,84389,9584)]`

Comment: first convert columns to rows - ie using `for` loop - next use `sort()` or `sorted()` on every row.

Answer (score 3):

Just `zip` the tuple of numbers to transpose them and then `sort` each tuple in reverse order

```
>>> [sorted(tup, reverse=True) for tup in zip(*(ppl[1:] for ppl in PPL))]
[[4937439, 843984, 2393], [93489348, 954975, 94374], [4387494, 84389, 9584]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution: `slice tuple-> sort tuple -> merge it -> cast it.`

```
>>> list(map(tuple,map(lambda x:[x[0]] + sorted(x[1:],reverse=True),PPL)))
[('Amy', 93489348, 84389, 2393), ('Blaise', 4937439, 4387494, 954975), ('Mint', 843984, 94374, 9584)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas

```
lis=[("Amy",2393,93489348,84389),
       ("Blaise",4937439,954975,4387494),
       ("Mint",843984,94374,9584)]

import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame(lis).drop(0,axis=1)
a=df.values
a.sort(axis=1)
a[:, ::-1]
```

Output:

```
array([[93489348,    84389,     2393],
       [ 4937439,  4387494,   954975],
       [  843984,    94374,     9584]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas and check what sorting you need (e.g.: [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) or [here](https://datatofish.com/sort-pandas-dataframe/))

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating a dataframe object from listoftuples
df1 = pd.DataFrame(PPL,columns= ['0', '1', '2', '3']) 

# sort it as you like it:
df1.sort_values(by=['1', '2','3'])

      0     1       2           3
0   Amy     2393    93489348    84389
2   Mint    843984  94374       9584
1   Blaise  4937439 954975      4387494
```